# How to use String as id in android?

Tags: android, string

My String is `Nevada` from edittext
and my id is `R.id.nevada` 
as my string is Nevada in this n is capital in id it won't accept. So i want to use like

```
String temp = "Nevada";
String lower = temp.toLowerCase();
R.id.lower
```

i know that this lower to use all areas
like this i am using all 48 areas as id but i must use this id dynamically without using multiple if conditions

Comment: What exactly do you want? Clarify

Comment: id needs to be in lower letter. not its text. What exactly do you want?

Comment: i have multiple areas id and its text is Nevada and its id nevada like this there are other 47 areas. So when i am clicking on that i must run same code and in that i am using "R.id.nevada". This is "R.id.nevada"  to be dynamically how?

Comment: You can't use String as Id. The Id should be an integer. And you can set the Id dynamically by setId(int value). But the value should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method

```
public static int getResId(String fieldName, Context context, Class<?> c) {

    try {
        Field field= c.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        return field.getInt(field);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

For an Example:

```
getResId("nevada", context, id.class);
```